# set alarm for my Database Values?

Tags: android, android-studio

how to set alarm for my Database Values because db values are string .for example my date and time is 10:33 AM4/11/2015 .

```
    Date m_date = new Date();              
   SimpleDateFormat m_dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aayyyy-MM-dd");

            try {

                m_date = m_dateFormat.parse("1:40 PM4/11/2015");
            } catch (ParseException p_e) {
                p_e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m_date.getTime();

            String s = String.valueOf(m_date.getTime());
            System.out.println("Pakistan " + s);
          //  Log.d("Tag Name", s);
            long foo = Long.parseLong(s);
            System.out.println("Pakistan " + foo);
            long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + foo;
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            Toast displayVal = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alaram Set After 10 sec it will work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            displayVal.show();
```

Comment: `my date and time is 10:33 AM4/11/2015` A valid TimeString for SQLite is `2015-11-04 10:33`. For your reference: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `m_dateFormat` **hh:mm aayyyy-MM-dd** is **not** used for **"1:40 PM4/11/2015"**

Please use "**hh:mm aaMM/dd/yyyy**"

Then you don't need to parse the time from a String.

At last, the time for AlarmManager is **UTC time** when using `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`

```
   Date m_date = new Date();              
   SimpleDateFormat m_dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaMM/dd/yyyy");
   try {
       m_date = m_dateFormat.parse("1:40 PM4/11/2015");
   } catch (ParseException p_e) {
       p_e.printStackTrace();
   }
   long time = m_date.getTime();
   System.out.println("Pakistan " + time);
   Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

[Click here to check more about AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP)